# Windows service only running on the machine it generated

Tags: .net

I have built setup file for my windows service in visual studio 2010.Its working fine on my machine. but when im installing it to another machine it executed but nothing happens. I cant figure out whats happening.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
#if (!DEBUG)


        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        {
            new EmailService()

        };
        EmailService listener = new EmailService();
        listener.temp();

        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
 #else

    EmailService listener = new EmailService();
        listener.WorkerThreadFunc();
        listener.ServiceEmailMethod();

 #endif

     }
 }
```

Comment: How are you installing it? Are you using the sc.exe tool? Also, post an code snippet of your program.cs so we can make sure it's started correctly.

Comment: im installing it using setup exe and msi file. Which is generated from vs2010 setup project,and starting it from task schedular.

Comment: did you examine the windows logs for any messages that might have popped up there?

Comment: no logs are created for my service...

Comment: I think that @Andrei is referring to the Windows Event Log. It may contain information about if the service has failed to start for some reason.

Comment: its showing no information for my service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your service will start only if it's a release build. Could it be that you run the release build on your machine, but the debug build on the other machine?

Comment: can you explain how i can do release build ?

Comment: @incomplete: it suprises me a bit that you don't know how to make release or debug builds, since your code includes conditional compiler directives (`#if`, `#else` and `#endif`) to control what is included in the different builds. But the toolbars in Visual Studio typically contain a combo box that will say either "Debug" or "Release", where you can choose the kind of biuld you want to make.

Comment: yup i know but its giving me whole lot of errors if i do so. I wanna know the better way.

Comment: @incomplete: then your first step should be to investigate and correct those errors.

Comment: Im getting-"Installer class property only valid for assemblies" ..any idea ?

Comment: Im using debug build for my machine its working like a charm, but in other nothing happens..

Comment: Very weird, when i dont add custom action, my windows service works flawlessly on every machine ive tested recently. wow!!!!

Comment: thanks for helping guys, as my problem is resolved im gonna mark Fredrik's answer as accepted.